# Unable to overwrite default mui style with custom css

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

i am unable to overwrite default styles used by Material UI through my custom styles using css , below is the attached code for reference ,Kinldy guide what am i doing wrong or have missed ,Thanks in advance

React code from .jsx file

```
    import "./StreamDashboard.css";
    import { Button } from "@mui/material";
    const StreamDashboard = () => {
      return (
        <div className="stream_container">
        <Button className="config_button" variant="contained">
        Edit Config
        </Button>
        </div>
      );
     };

    export default StreamDashboard;
```

CSS code from .css file

```
    .stream_container {
       height: 100vh;
     }
    .config_button {
      color: black;
      background-color: yellow;
      border-radius: 10px;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I import styles is like this:

> I Always use *.module.css to avoid class name conflicts

```js
import styles from "./StreamDashboard.module.css";
```

then in code you can do this (for example):

```js
import styles from "./StreamDashboard.module.css";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
const StreamDashboard = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.stream_container}>
      <Button className={styles.config_button} variant="contained">
        Edit Config
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StreamDashboard;
```

file StreamDashboard.module.css contains:

```css
.stream_container {
 /* styles */
}

.config_button {
 /* styles */
}
```

So basically you have to import css styles with a name(in above example `styles`) and then get the classes using `styles.css_class_name`

```js
className = {styles.your_css_class_name}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a shot and append in the end to every style you wanna override  `!important`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).